# Launcher creation errors

Tags: launcher

I had created a launcher for my application an the launcher file is :-

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name[en_IN]=stt
Exec=/home/sijoy/Documents/stt_new/STT/STT
Comment[en_IN]=System Tool Trace
Name=stt
Comment=System Tool Trace
Icon=/home/sijoy/splash.bmp
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

but it is showing the error of not able to get the required dependent libraries,as Caused by: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /home/sijoy/./liblog4cxx.so`

Actually I am trying to create a launcher for my application which is not installed on my system but kept at a certain location with all its dependent files and runs fine if I directly click the executable going to that folder is it possible to create a launcher for it, if so how?

Comment: Looks like something related to the environment; as of now you're running your executable using `dash`, try running it using `bash`: replace `Exec=/home/sijoy/Documents/stt_new/STT/STT` with `Exec=bash -c 'Exec=/home/sijoy/Documents/stt_new/STT/STT'`

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for the file `./liblog4cxx.so` in the default current directory, which is your home directory `/home/sijoy`.  You probably need to set the current directory to the directory the executable is in, `/home/sijoy/Documents/stt_new/STT`, to find the file `/home/sijoy/Documents/stt_new/STT/liblog4cxx.so`.

Try adding the following line to the end of your desktop file:

```
Path=/home/sijoy/Documents/stt_new/STT
```

Despite its name, this sets the current directory and has no effect on your `$PATH`.

Comment: @sijoy While it's nice to be thanked, if an [answer](//askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) solves your question, simply upvote it by clicking on the up arrow beside it, and accept the best one by clicking on the grey checkmark, which are the Ask Ubuntu ways of saying thank you.